# Does Janet of "The Good Place" get her name from Janet of "Rocky Horror Picture Show"?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show, the-good-place

I just finished watching *The Good Place* (and I loved it.)

It just came distinctly across my mind the feeling that the name of Janet (or of Janets) is somehow related to the Janet of *The Rocky Horror Picture Show*.

Does anyone know if the authors of *The Good Place* have indeed taken the name from there, or is there another reason for which they choose that name?

Comment: I suppose they both have their limited view of the world's possibilities expanded by a colourful cast of characters, but Good Place Janet seems a lot more informed about the story's setting than Rocky Horror Janet.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Good Janet is literally omniscient. I'm not sure that counts as a limited view.

Comment: @OrangeDog: sure — I was thinking that perhaps Janet wasn't aware of some of the  revelations about the nature of the Good and Bad Places that occur during the show, so in that sense she had her world view expanded. She also fell in love, which I thought wasn't considered possible for Janets. But I have pretty vague recollections of the details, so I could be way off-base.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per Vanity Fair, the name was simply a placeholder that stuck.

> *O.K.—but why name her Janet? Simple: **when Schur writes scripts, he defaults to calling his characters “Jim” and “Janet” until he can think of something better. In this case, the provisional name stuck.** Which is appropriate, since Schur’s method means the name “Janet” has taken on a grander, more ubiquitous meaning for him—it’s the ideal term for an omniscient character, someone who is everything and nothing all at once.*
>
> — [How The Good Place Built Janet, TV’s Most Scene-Stealing Not-a-Robot](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/06/the-good-place-janet-darcy-carden-mike-schur-interview-nbc)